# RegisterClientScript not work for set array value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, registerclientscriptblock

I define one array in my javascript.js file :

```
var rowPermissions = [];
```

and I set values in asp.net code as Client Script Block in my usercontrol.ascx page :

```
if (permission == true)
    folderPermissions = "rowPermissions[" + folderId + "] = '1';";
else
    folderPermissions = "rowPermissions[" + folderId + "] = '0';";

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(upExpander, upExpander.GetType(), "row Permission"+folderId + Guid.NewGuid(), folderPermissions, true);
```

but it won't work, and the array is not filled. why? and how can I solve this????

Comment: What is folderId? Errors in the console? I guess is `XXXX is not defined.`

Comment: folderId defined and is an integer , if I set this value in one simple variable it worked!!!!.

Comment: So what is the error? Is there one in the console? Is the error on the serverside? Is it being rendered to the client? Details are needed.

Comment: I don't know, no error raise in console , but array value not set successfully

Comment: Do you see the code in the source?

Comment: No, asp.net clientscripts not see in source

Comment: Your RegisterClientScriptBlock line seems wrong...ah wait you are using ScriptManager instead of ClientScriptManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give little infos so I can only guess that your array definition is executed later than the rendered script by `RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

Look at the html source of the page.

Try to use the [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript (...);
```